# Is there a website or list somewhere of which countries need a full page of a passport to issue a visa?

Tags: visas, online-resources, passports

I'm on a huge trip at the moment and have some big plans for after winter if I manage not to spend all my money.

But several of the countries I'm thinking of going to require me to get a visa and I'm running low on blank pages for those countries which require a full page like Armenia, India, and Vietnam do.

**Is there a central place where we can look up what destinations require a full passport page for their visas to citizens of which countries?**

I'm an Australian citizen and some of the places I'm considering visiting are Abkhazia, Azerbaijan, Iran, Kuwait, Mongolia, Nagorno Karabakh, and Russia.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just get a new passport? ;)

Comment: I can only get a full new passport by going back to Australia. I can get a temporary passport from an embassy but they are only valid for six months and many if not all countries require six months minimum validity of your passport to grant a visa or entry.

Comment: Can confirm that both Mongolia and Russia require full pages ;)

Comment: Really? You can't get a new Australian passport at any Australian consulate?

Comment: @JoelSpolsky: No I lost my passport in Canada once twenty years ago and actually got one of these temporary ones. You need to upgrade it to a full one, including paying the usual fee, when you get back to Australia... Unless this has changed over the years...

Comment: @JoelSpolsky: OK I read up and it seems these days I could get a new full passport while travelling. It turns out that renewing an existing passport is different to replacing a lost passport. It ain't cheap though. **$226** for a normal one, **$340** for one with extra pages. But at least now I know so I can factor it into my decisions on this trip.

Comment: Not on your list but useful to know: Egypt, Zimbabwe and Zambia all require full page visas all available at the border.

Answer (score 10):

The vast majority of countries that require you to get a visa in advance (as opposed to getting one "at the border") will require a full page for the Visa.

If you're running low on pages, many/most Australian Embassy/Consulates around the world will be able to issue a new full passport. The price and process is basically the same if you were to do it in Australia - including the fact that you need to send in your old passport if you're doing it by mail.  You'll get the old one back, but with the "machine readable strip" removed, which means any visa's you have in the old passport will still be valid.

I recently renewed my Passport through the Australian consulate in San Francisco for the same reason (~5 years left on the old passport, but I was almost out of pages). Took about a week from when I posted it in until when I got the new passport back.

Comment: That's a good point but there are also countries which issue full page visas on arrival. I got one crossing into Armenia from Georgia last year.

Comment: Actually I'm finding out about more and more countries that have e-visas that do not require anything taking up a full page of your passport when you arrive. I could've gone to Cambodia on this trip between Thailand and Laos if I had known. It seems Armenia has them too.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a web site that lists these, but a Google image search helped. Of the countries you mentioned the following have full page visas:

- Abkhazia,
- Azerbaijan
- Iran
- Mongolia
- Nagorno Karabakh
- Russia

A Kuwait tourist visa seems to be a smaller sticker, not a whole page.

Other countries with whole page visas include:

- Vietnam
- Belarus
- Indonesia

The last one is an example for one which you can on arrival.

Comment: Indonesia is half page visa.. i have pages with two indonesian visas on them.

Answer (score 3):

The [Gallery of passport stamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_passport_stamps_by_country_or_territory) may help you - it at least indicates which stamps are just small stamps and which countries use an entire page.

It shows the entry stamps, exit stamps, and visas, so you can calculate how much space you might require.